# Making a Flutter app accept incoming intents

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, android-contacts

The [Flutter for Android developers](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) docs explain how to make a Flutter app accept incoming Android intents, and give a code example for accepting **Share** intents. I've reproduced it and it works great.

But I'm now trying to make my app accept **other types of intents**, specifically the **Edit contact** intent, so that when I use the default Phone app and click on a contact, my app is suggested to complete the action.

I've tried all possible combinations of `<intent-filter>` I could find after googling and searching GitHub, but nothing could get it to work. To give a few:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2"/>
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" android:host="contacts"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" android:host="contacts"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact" android:host="contacts"/>
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:host="contacts"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
    <data
        android:host="com.android.contacts"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" />
    <data
        android:host="com.android.contacts"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CONTACT"/>
</intent-filter>

etc.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hi, this might help you, have a look at the following URL:
https://muetsch.io/how-to-receive-sharing-intents-in-flutter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Contacts app you're using.

Each device can ship with a maker-specific contacts app (e.g. Samsung Contacts), 
a Google provided app (Google Contacts), 
the service provider may install their own Contacts app, 
or the user might be using an app installed from Google Play (e.g. Contacts+).

Each such app may choose to launch the editor via an intent other apps may catch, or just launch it's own built-in editor without involving the intent system.

If there is an intent to be catch, you can find out what that is by checking LogCat, filtering to the tag `ActivityManager`, it shows all intents being thrown on the device, so you can study it to find out what are the intent specifics you need to catch.

Comment: Wow! Brilliant! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, building on marmor's answer above to show the concrete steps:

```
$ adb logcat | grep ActivityTaskManager
```

```
[...]
04-01 18:09:27.306  1384  4229 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/contact cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity (has extras)} from uid 10065
[...]
```

So all I had to do was add this to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact"/>
</intent-filter>
```